# Reading String and combining similar terms in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with root words throughout and would like to consolidate them in r, how would I go about doing that?
I would like to take something like this...

```
  Name        Count Location
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   
1 Car_street      1 A       
2 Car_garaged     3 A       
3 Car             2 A       
4 Bird_fly        3 A       
5 Bird_landed     2 A       
6 Bird            2 A  
7 Plane_fly       3 A
8 Plane_landed    2 A
9 Plane           1 A
```

and produce this

```
  Name        Count Location
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   
1 Car             6 A       
2 Bird            7 A       
7 Plane           6 A
```

I'm still learning r so pointing me in any direction would be fine, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the substring after the `_` (including `_`) and do a group by operation

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Name = trimws(Name, whitespace = "_.*"), Location) %>%
    summarise(Count = sum(Count), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Name  Location Count
  <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 Bird  A            7
2 Car   A            6
3 Plane A            6
```

---

Or use `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(Count ~ ., transform(df1, Name = trimws(Name, whitespace = "_.*")), sum)
   Name Location Count
1  Bird        A     7
2   Car        A     6
3 Plane        A     6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Car_street", "Car_garaged", "Car", "Bird_fly", 
"Bird_landed", "Bird", "Plane_fly", "Plane_landed", "Plane"), 
    Count = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Location = c("A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```